# Login to other Stack Exchange sites with the same account?

Tags: support, profile-page, login

I cannot login with the same account to gamedev.stackexchange.com, but I thought the account is shared between the Stack Exchange sites. I login via email.

Comment: You don't seem to have an [account there](https://stackexchange.com/users/10316793/cmdlp?tab=accounts). You first need to click *Join this community* in the topbar. After that Universal Login will work

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/260153/global-auth-is-dead-long-live-universal-login

Comment: Usually, I just try to answer or comment, and I get prompted to join up.  One click and I can carry on with my elitist, egoist, deriding, insulting, unhelpful and unwelcome trolling on the new site.